# Disqus comments only show up on newest post

Tags: comments, disqus

I've setup Disqus comments on our company blog ([link](https://www.thebouqs.com/blog/))

By creating a comments.php file with:

```
<div id="disqus_thread" style="margin-top:50px;position:relative;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = 'thebouqs';
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

and on the single.php file

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'footer' );
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
    comments_template();
}
$previous_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
$next_post     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
```

but the comments box only displays on the newest post.  I reached out to Disqus support but they haven't replied to me since the beginning of the week.  I attempted to use the prepackaged Disqus plugin and it did not seem to work at all (didn't display comments anywhere) so that's why I went with the universal javascript version instead.

Comment: Were the posts that the comments are shown created after you added Disqus?

Comment: No, all posts existed prior to setting up Disqus.